# Executing sql statement and storing value in variable

Tags: sql, unix

I have a shell script which is trying to execute a simple sql statement and intend to store the result in single variable. But i am unable to do it.I am using Cygwin and intended to use it in unix.
Find below script

```
echo "executing a script.."
var=(sqlplus cimnewuser/cimnewuser@cimnew
select ID from catalog where tablename='MCT_35618';
exit)
echo "$var"
```

it is giving me error. I am new to executing sql manipulation in  sql.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `$`.

Try:

```
var=$(sqlplus cimnewuser/cimnewuser@cimnew
select ID from catalog where tablename='MCT_35618';
exit)
```

Alternatively, you can use backticks:

```
var=`sqlplus ...`
```

Comment: thank you...i modified it but it is not echoing result and gets stuck there.........

Comment: modified script is....var=$(`sqlplus cimnewuser/cimnewuser@cimnew
select ID from catalog where tablename='MCT_35618';
exit`)
echo "$var"

Comment: Try putting the sql commands in a file, say `commands.sql` and execute `var=$(sqlplus cimnewuser/cimnewuser@cimnew @command.sql)`

Comment: it worked but as i said i want to store only value like var=34720 and not the whole story....its echoing...

Comment: SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Fri Jun 21 10:55:16 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options


        ID
----------
     35618

Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options.....i want only result to be stored

Comment: There is a `-S` (silent) option. And `set pagesize 0` to turn off the column headers. I can't figure out how to suppress the completely pointless blank line at the end though.